# Uncaught TypeError: chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown is not a function at Object.success - HighCharts

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, highcharts

I have a Highchartjs implementation that I am trying to implement, I am getting json data and trying to build a stacked bar chart drilldown. I have the data from the api and when I try to populate it,  I end up getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown is not a
> function
> at Object.success

This is my implementation so far

```
function loadProvinceStackedChart() {
            var dataSeries = [];    
            var drill_level = 0;                                 
            var chart = {
                type: 'column',
                marginBottom: 120,
                events: {
                    drilldown: function (e) {
                        var pointName = e.point.name;
                         $.ajax({
                                  url: 'api/getDistrictData/'+ e.point.name,
                                  type: 'GET',
                                  success: function (data) {
                                         //console.log('district data is', data);
                                          var labuploadedData = [];
                                          var labPndingData =[];
                                          $.each(data, function(key, item){
                                          //console.log('item q', item);
                                           var u = {  
                                                     name: item.district_Name,
                                                     y: item.labUploaded,
                                                     drilldown: false
                                                                                                                                         
                                                     };
                                            var p = {
                                                       name: item.district_Name,
                                                       y: item.pending,
                                                       drilldown: false
                                                      };
                                            labuploadedData.push(u);
                                            labPndingData.push(p);
                                         });
                               // console.log('are of point', pointName);
                                  var chart = this;
                                  drilldowns4 = {
                                                  pointName: {
                                                             name: 'Uploaded',
                                                             color: '#228B22',
                                                             data: labuploadedData
                                                             }
                                                           },
                                  drilldowns6 = {
                                                  pointName: {
                                                            name: 'Pending',
                                                            color: '#FF0000',
                                                            data: labPndingData

                                                                }
                                                           },
                                            
                                series = drilldowns4[e.point.name],
                                series3 = drilldowns6[e.point.name];
                                                      
                              chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                             chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series3);
                                                        
                              chart.applyDrilldown();
                                                                 
                                                    }      
                                                    
                                                });                    
                    }
                }
            };
```

I am trying to have the chart methods inside the success function ,but they keep throwing an error above. How can I display the stacked chart correctly from the data from the api?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to implement the ajax query in the drilldown module like this.

```
events: {
  drilldown: function(e) {

    // The Endpoint URL
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
    fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Render the Response Status
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = response.status;
        // Parse the body as JSON
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        // Render the parsed body
        document.getElementById('result_json').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json);
      })
    }
}
```

At this forum post it's other example how to handle ajax query in the drilldown event.
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40115#p138962